# How to share a variable between master layout and a view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following static method in my Guest model to retrieve all guests at location 1:

> ```
> public static function getGuests()
> {
>     return self::where('location_id', '=', 1)->get();
> }
> ```

I also got the following static method to retrieve and display the number of guests at location 1.

> ```
> public static function getCount()
> {
>     return self::getGuests()->count();
> }
> ```

I later call the `getGuests()` in my `GuestController` and pass all the guests to the view `guests/index.blade.php` to display data in a table.

I also call `getCount()` from my `BaseController` (see below) to make the count variable available both in the menubar in the `layout/layout.blade.php` file and the header of `guests/index.blade.php`.

> ```
> View::share('numGuests', Guest::getCount());
> ```

By doing this i naturally end up with an expensive duplicated query to the DB since `GetCount()` calls `getGuests()`. Is there a better way to display the number of counts, both in the master layout file and the embedded view, without having to do the duplicate query call?

Comment: So your problem is that when you share `Guest::getCount()`, it runs the query in `getGuests()` even though that function has been executed before?

Comment: Jupp, more or less. I found a solution now though. Thanks for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick and low-cost solution by simply just calling the `count()` directly on the query, instead on the function call.

> ```
> public static function getAll($locationId)
> {
>     return self::whereLocationId($locationId)->with('country')->get();
> }
>
> public static function countAll($locationId)
> {
>     return self::whereLocationId($locationId)->count();
> }
> ```

This left me me with two separate queries, where the `count` is onsiderably lower cost:

```
select * from `guests` where `location_id` = '2'
```

and

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `location_id` = '2'
```

It can probably be made even quicker by selecting only the neccesary columns instead of *. In cases where the query is more complicated and require more `WHERE` clauses, it can easily be kept DRY by using [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). Thanks for massaging my brain.

Answer (score 0):

`View::share` shouldn't be calling the `Guest::getCount()' twice.  It should just call it once and then pass it in.  If not though can't you just cache the value in a variable and then pass it in?  Then its definitely not getting queried twice.

```
$guestCount = Guest::getCount();
View::share('numGuests', $guestCount);
```

I might be misunderstanding here - are you also calling `Guest::getCount()` later on from your GuestController?  Sorry - can't comment on main questions yet to ask.

Comment: I'm calling `getGuests()` later from the `GuestController` and `getCount()` both from the layout and the view which extends it. I found a neat solution now. Thanks for trying to help me out.